# How to logout from eclipse SVN in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. I am using eclipse indigo with SVN repo. i have taken zip file of eclipse from my friend. My problem is my friend already save its svn credentials  with it and i dont know how logout from it. I want to enter my SVN credentials with eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you guys are using SVN, you basically should not send Zip files to each other :-)

What I would suggest:

1. Copy and archive the content of the project you have to a backup directory
2. Delete the project within Eclipse (click the remove from disk option too)
3. Check out the project using your own SVN client (I don't know which one you use, but it'll ask for your own credentials).
4. Voilà, you're ready! :-)

Hope that helps.

Comment: i did this steps several time before but i dont know what is the magic  happens after reading your ans. thx :)

Comment: Might have been the `.svn` directory(ies). Probably when you check out onto an existing project it does not overwrite existing configuration.